# I'm trying to add button that each row have it and it adds another row at bottom of it

Tags: javascript

What im tryin to do is Each row will have button and when button clicked add 1 row at bottom of it

```
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        for(var i=0;i<rowCount;i++){
            table.rows[i].onclick = function(){
                rIndex = this.rowIndex;
                document.getElementById("cod_cad").value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
            }
        }

        for(var i=0;i<rowCount;i++){
            table.rows[i].cells[2].onclick = function(){
                rIndex = this.rowIndex;
                var newrow = table.insertRow(i);
                var newcel1 = newrow.insertCell(0);
                var newcel2 = newrow.insertCell(1);
                var newcel3 = newrow.insertCell(2);

                newcel1.innerHTML = 'Compartimento';
                newcel2.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="cod_cad">';
                newcel3.innerHTML = '<img src="plus.png" alt="+" width="20px" height="20px"/>';
            }
        }
```

The first loop works to show clicked row in

Comment: It looks like to me that your `table` variable is never declared anywhere with a `querySelector`. You have to tell it which table to work on. Either that or it's assigned outside the scope of these functions. Also, what is the result you're getting? Is it not doing anything at all? Adding the row above? Adding the row at the bottom of the table?

Comment: Oh, I didn't show that I already declared it as global variable. getelementsById of that table that i want.
What im getting is if I put i in insertRow's parameter, it only add at bottom of 5th row. If I put 'this' in parameter, on top of all. And these arent the way I want.